# F2PY - Access module parameter from subroutine

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I cannot get f2py to reference a parameter from a module in a separate subroutine where it is used to defined an input array dimension. I.e. the paramter is defeind in a module:

```
! File: testmod.f90
MODULE testmod
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dimsize = 20
END MODULE testmod
```

and the parameter dimsize needs to be referenced in a subroutine (NOT contained in the module) in another file, which will be the entry point for my python module:

```
! File testsub.f90
SUBROUTINE testsub(arg)
USE testmod
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: arg(dimsize)
END SUBROUTINE testsub
```

I compile like this:

```
f2py -m testmod  -h testmod.pyf testsub.f90
pgf90 -g -Mbounds -Mchkptr -c -fPIC testmod.f90 -o testmod.o
pgf90 -g -Mbounds -Mchkptr -c -fPIC testsub.f90 -o testsub.o
f2py -c testmod.pyf testmod.o testsub.o
```

but get this error:

```
testmodmodule.c: In function 'f2py_rout_testmod_testsub':
testmodmodule.c:180: error: 'dimsize' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I have tried modifying testsub.g90 to include the following directive, as suggested ni other posts:

```
SUBROUTINE testsub(arg)
USE testmod
!f2py integer, parameter :: dimsize
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: arg(dimsize)
END SUBROUTINE testsub
```

but to no avail. I need to keep the subroutine separate from the module.

How can I get f2py to correctly resolve the variable `dimsize`?

TIA

Comment: I am having the same problem with `ifort` on Windows 7, using f2py version 2. The problem seems to occur at the _first_ f2py call, where I see the error: 
`In: :testmoddd:testsub.f90:testsub
get_useparameters: no module testmod info used by testsub
In: :testmoddd:testsub.f90:testsub
       getarrlen:variable "dimsize" undefined`

Comment: @bdforbes: hmmm....I am beginning to think this is just a serious shortcoming of f2py when using Fortran90. I should have stuck to F77!

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since this question has gotten any activity, but I figured out the problem so I thought I'd post it for anyone else who has this issue. The problem is that while the Fortran code is perfectly valid, the C wrapper generated by F2PY doesn't know what dimsize is when it checks that arrays are the correct size (within the C wrapper, it's encapsulated in some kind of module structure).

Just change this code:

```
SUBROUTINE testsub(arg)
USE testmod
!f2py integer, parameter :: dimsize
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: arg(dimsize)
END SUBROUTINE testsub
```

to this:

```
SUBROUTINE testsub(arg)
USE testmod
!f2py integer, intent(aux) :: dimsize
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: arg(dimsize)
END SUBROUTINE testsub
```

This will "Define auxiliary C variable in F2PY generated wrapper function". As the [Scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/signature-file.html) say, this is "Useful to save parameter values so that they can be accessed in initialization expression of other variables".

I haven't tested this with your code, but I've tested it with a similar situation I was having.

Comment: nice! I also had this problem when declaring an array in a subroutine whose dimension used a parameter defined in the *same* module, and this fixed it.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. The only difference is `dimsize` is not defined with the `parameter` attribute in the module. F2PY compiles but then when I run the subroutine in python I get an error: `ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: having the same problem, any solution to this?

Comment: I don't understand what "The only difference is `dimsize` is not defined with the `parameter` attribute in the module" means. Does the same solution with `intent(aux)` not work? Perhaps it is worth opening a new question with these details in a MCVE?

Answer (score 1):

Although I've not tested it, I *think* you nearly have it with your original code.  We do something similar for some of our code, but with gfortran.

You shouldn't need to `f2py` the testmod.f90 file.  You should just compile it to an object file just like you would if this were normal Fortran:

```
pgf90 -g -Mbounds -Mchkptr -c -fPIC testmod.f90 -o testmod.o
```

Then you should be able to compile your testsub.f90 into a python-usable module with:

```
f2py --fcompiler=pgf90 --f90flags="-g -Mbounds -Mchkptr" -c testsub.f90 -m testsub testmod.o
```

That should build a testsub.so, or equivalent, letting you `import testsub` and then `testsub.testsub(my_arg)` in python.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried with a different compiler?  I've only ever used gfortran with f2py...

Comment: I've tried it again with --fcompiler=gfortran, but I get the same errors. It is essentially the c compiler that is producing the errors, not the fortran compiler. I think that f2py simply does not handle the F90 modules well...